# Getting "Access Denied" when loading a URL in JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to scrape some information of a page using the `jsdom.env` function. However, the page that gets returned in the `env()` callback is about how access is denied to the server instead of the content that I am hoping to see when I load the same URL in a browser.

Thus, there seems to be a difference in how the browser loads the page vs. how jsdom is loading it. Is this something which can be configured in the `jsdom` module?

**Edit:**

Example URL: `http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+20%22+Widescreen+Flat-Panel+LCD+Monitor/1422209.p?id=1218257754431&skuId=1422209`

**Update:**

The issue was jsdom not specifying the user-agent http header. Look at the detailed answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `jsdom` is not specifying a 'User-Agent' http header, which the bestbuy.com server are checking for. If its empty, access is denied. Currently, there is no way of specifying this through `jsdom` - https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/196

A workaround that worked for me to use the `request` module to get the page content and then pass then on to `jsdom` to work on. The `request` module allows you to specify a user agent

Example:

```
var request = require('request'),

getPage = function(someUri, callback) {
  request({uri: someUri, headers:{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("Fetched " +someUri+ " OK!");
    callback(body);
  });
}

getPage('http://www.bestbuy.com/', function(body) {
   console.log(body)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, cross-domain AJAX calls are not possible. 
More info here: http://m.snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj

Comment: How is this considered as cross-domain AJAX? I've successfully been able to use jsdom on other sites. I'm simply trying to load the page and traverse it using jquery locators

Comment: The issue turned out to be jsdom not sending the user-agent http header. Thanks for your help though!